# JSP, Servlets - proper way of managing website layout?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, layout, include

I am quite new to JSP, servlets, etc.
I am making a website for learning purposes. I would like it to have a classic layout - menu on the left, and content in central part. I came across problem: I want to make "dynamic menu". It would load some data from database (countries). I can do it on single page by creating a servlet that returns those countries for me.

```
@WebServlet("/countries")
public class LeagueCountriesServlet  extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req,resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req,resp);
}

void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LeaguesDAO dao =
            (LeaguesDAO)req.getServletContext().getAttribute("leaguesDAO");
    List<String> list = dao.getAllCountries();
    req.setAttribute("countrylist", list);
    RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("menulist.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

However, in fact it works only if I access "/countries". I would like to make it appear on many pages. 
I tried to solve it with including it in other JSPs

```
<jsp:include page="/countries" />
```

But this causes that website is being "cut" after that included part. 
What is the proper way to handle "layouts" like that?
I could generate response for this menu in every servlet, but it doesn't sound like a proper method.
I believe that i should divide template into two parts: pre-content holding header, menu, etc, and post-content holding footer etc, and include them in .jsp's used to display content-data coming from servlets. But how to avoid problems with dynamically generated menus?

```
<jsp:include page="before-content.jsp" />
   (here some code to display specified web page)
<jsp:include page="after-content.jsp" />
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should change path in @WebServlet("/countries") not in JSPs, web server (Tomcat/Jetty/etc) are dispatches http requests looking into servlet mapping. Afterwards your servlet points which jsp should be used to generate desired html page.

Comment: Ok, i understand this. But i want my servlet to be run under not ONE but MANY paths. I probably have not written it clearly enough.

Comment: You can create several servlets with different paths, or implement one common servlet and switch between paths:

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/pattern.html), implementing the Composite View Pattern or [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh3/SiteMesh+3+Overview), which uses the Decorator Pattern.

In Tiles you can define some templates for the header, footer and menu part and reuse them for every page.